# Get JSON object in c# from a web-request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, httpwebrequest

I need to get json data from an external domain. I used webrequest to get the response from a website. heres the code:

```
var search = umbraco.library.Request("search");
string Url = "http://ff.ss.dk/Suggest.ff?username=us&password=pass&channel=dk&format=JSON&query="+search;
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url);
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
```

this way i am getting an output like this

> [{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"Atrix h\u00E5ndcreme Dobbeltvirkende /100 Ml","type":"productName"},{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"V\u00E6gur magnetisk attraction","type":"productName"},{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"Bic kuglepen Atlantis , bl\u00E5","type":"productName"},{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"Laminering AT1256 31cm x30m A3","type":"productName"}]

I want to get this output data in JSON object format, that i can use this in my java script functions.
i think the output data is in inappropriate format because i have used streamreader function to get data.is there any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using **Json.Net** to serialize that content?

Comment: how is the output data 'inappropriate'? it appears to be valid JSON when validated at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @wal:data is in string format i need to convert it to json object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This data can be converted to json format using jQuery.parseJSON.

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

then we can access data like

```
 obj[0].id
```

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing an array name specifier, for example, this works:

```
{arrayName:[{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"Atrix h\u00E5ndcreme Dobbeltvirkende /100 Ml","type":"productName"},{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"V\u00E6gur magnetisk attraction","type":"productName"},{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"Bic kuglepen Atlantis , bl\u00E5","type":"productName"},{"hitCount":0,"imageURL":"","query":"Laminering AT1256 31cm x30m A3","type":"productName"}]}
```